# Continuous speech recognition in android app without google popup

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, continuous

I am working on a project on "Home Automation" system with Android app and Microcontroller , connecting them through Bluetooth module. I have incorporated "speech to text" for voice commands. Although , it works well with the built-in google speech recognition api. All I need is a continuous speech recognition and without the google voice pop-up.
I have seen a similar app on playstore "speechnotes" that works exactly i wish to develop. And it works totally offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Droid Speech](https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech) it supports continuous voice recognition and also will work offline if the speech package for the required language is installed in the device.

Setting the library in your project is very simple and with a few lines of code you can easily start using speech recognition.

An example,

Add the below in your Gradle file,

```
compile 'com.github.vikramezhil:DroidSpeech:v2.0.3’
```

In your Activity,

```
DroidSpeech droidSpeech = new DroidSpeech(this, null);
droidSpeech.setOnDroidSpeechListener(this);
```

To start droid speech to listen to user voice call the method,

```
droidSpeech.startDroidSpeechRecognition();
```

The speech result will be triggered at,

```
@Override
public void onDroidSpeechFinalResult(String finalSpeechResult)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the speech result 
}
```

Comment: This works. But, need to add the following line in project-level gradle: Gradle dependency:

Add the following to your project level build.gradle:
`code`
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
'code'
Add this to your app build.gradle:
`code`
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.vikramezhil:DroidSpeech:v2.0.3’
}  `code`

Comment: @ Vikram Ezhil Im getting error Error:(22, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.vikramezhil:DroidSpeech:v2.0.3

Comment: I attempted this through AIDE and it doesn't work it keeps saying "the dependency can't be found". Any ideas on how to use DroidSpeech through the AIDE android app?

Comment: @Vikram Ezhil I get a null exception if do "DroidSpeech droidSpeech = new DroidSpeech(this, null);" and it points to "DroidSpeech.startLanguageReceiver(DroidSpeech.java:104) at com.vikramezhil.droidspeech.DroidSpeech.<init>(DroidSpeech.java:81)"  Any help?

Comment: DroidSpeech is a licensed one so could you please suggest any free library?

Comment: @SathickIbrahim DroidSpeech is licensed under Apache 2.0 which is free. There is also this new version of the library written in Kotlin in case you are interested- https://github.com/vikramezhil/DroidSpeech2.0

Comment: @VikramEzhil DroidSpeech also works the same as default SpeechRecognizer. After a few seconds, it automatically stops the listening then I need to restart it again. Is there any way for continuous speech recognition?

Comment: Hi, I want it work offline, how do I down load the speech package for the language.

Comment: this lib seem dead, any other solution please